# I made a button to display the textfield value

Tags: swift

I made a button to display the textfield value (I used cellForRowAtIndexPath to enter the values) but I can not display them the first time I click

function to display textfield values:

```
func DoneA(sender: UIButton!) {

        print("Action called")
        print(val3)
        print(val4)
        print(val5)

}
```

And this to enter textfield values:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell55", forIndexPath: indexPath) as!EditProfileTableViewCell


    switch (indexPath.row)
    {

    case 0:

         cell.lab.text = "Photo"
         let imageName = "avatar.png"
         let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
         let newImage = resizeImage(image!, toTheSize: CGSizeMake(70, 70))
         let cellImageLayer: CALayer?  = cell.avatar.layer
         cellImageLayer!.cornerRadius = cellImageLayer!.frame.size.width / 2
         cellImageLayer!.masksToBounds = true
         cell.avatar.image = newImage
         cell.txt.hidden = true




    case 1:
        cell.lab.text = "Firstname"
        //cell.txt.text = self.value1
        val3 = cell.txt.text!




    case 2:
        cell.lab.text = "Lastname"
       // cell.txt.text = self.value2
        val4 =  cell.txt.text!

    case 3:
        cell.lab.text = "Username"
        //cell.txt.text = self.value3
        val5 =  cell.txt.text!





    default :
        break
    }



    return cell


}
```

Comment: Show your trying code

Comment: make more clarity to the question.

Comment: Add some more stuff to clarify your question.

Comment: I put you my code please help me

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in this case you will get the empty strings for all the variable (val3, val4, val5).

You can get the text fields value by the following two methods:

1. Use the textField delegate method `textFieldShouldEndEditing(_:)` [learn from here about textField delegate methods](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate). Here in this method you can set copy the text of textField to variable like `self.val3 = textField.text`. You need to use same switch case as you've used in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.
2. You can define three textField variable (ex. `var firstNameField: UITextField?`) as the class instance methods and then assign these variables value in cell for row at index path like:
   `self.firstNameField = cell.text` for case 1 and so on for all the textField cases.
   Now, in done button action use `self.firstNameField?.text` then you can get the current text of testField.

But I'll recommend to use the first one